# Parse 155 Error - Exceeded request limit

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I get this error while developing an iOS application using parse service.

```
Error Domain=Parse Code=155 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Parse error 155.)" UserInfo=0x1e0d8b00 {code=155, error=This application has exceeded its request limit.}
```

While i understand what the error means, i don't know how i can make 30 requests per second, when i hardly make 2-5 requests per minute. I can see spikes in the parse analytics too. My question is what constitutes a request - is it a parse call like `saveInBackgroundWithBlock:` or `deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:` on the PFObject? If so i don't think i can ever make 30 requests per second while developing with a single parse object to play around in the cloud.

---

### **UPDATE**

I logged my parse calls which are well extracted to be not duplicated and logged the calls. After 10 minutes this is what the count looked like (`file` is `PFFile:getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:`). Please consider the bottom most values as latest as it continuous logging of incrementing counts in a dictionary -

```
file : 3
find : 1
file : 3
find : 3
save : 1
file : 3
find : 5
save : 2
Error: This application has exceeded its request limit. (Code: 155, Version: 1.2.19)
ERROR in finding entities - Error Domain=Parse Code=155 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Parse error 155.)" UserInfo=0x21dd3070 {code=155, error=This application has exceeded its request limit.}
```

As can be seen, just after some time the 155 error is thrown. I am confused if the request counting of parse is the way i imagine or if the parse iOS SDK does multiple requests internaly for my one `PFQuery:findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:` for example.

---

### **UPDATE 2**

Setup a network proxy to see what calls parse iOS sdk makes when run in simulator -

Here is the screenshot when i got an error saying request limit exceeded -

[image]

And Here is parse api request graph in their website -

[image]

There never was 400 requests made in the first place as can bee seen by the network proxy report which says 2 requests. Definitely something is wrong with parse and they don't like free plan users which is a shame as they could have said so and I would either have bought a plan or moved elsewhere. And the parse folks are not responding...

Comment: The parse dashboard will show your request rate. Do you perhaps have any requests inside a loop that shouldn't be?

Comment: @Paulw11 Parse dashboard does show spikes > 60. But it is impossible that i am making anything like that. Some sort of server request log would have helped.

Comment: It sounds like it isn't impossible because it is happening. Do you perhaps execute pfquery in a loop?  Perhaps use the profile tool in Instruments to check calls into parse

Answer (score 1):

You have to click on the **Performance** tab which comes in the bottom-most position (Highlighted in Blue) of the events to know the Request/Second Log. If the Request exceeds the Yellow Boundary then you will get the `This application has exceeded its request limit` error.

[image: Parse Performance Log]

If you have your Requests/Second going above the Yellow boundary, then you will have to use the [Slider](https://parse.com/account) to to buy more request limit.

The Following is my Events log, Do note that this is not the request/second log shown below. What you need is the First image.

[image: Parse Events Log]

For getting the file transfer Log you have to click on the Plus (+) button on the right of `API Requests` on the second Image.